# Capture self was never used

Tags: swift, queue, alert

I don't post the entire code because it's really too large. Anyway, it's a user registration built this way.

There is a modal whose child is a pageViewController:

- the first page is for Login;
- the second page is for Registration;

From Login you can reach Registration and, once registered, pageViewController should automatically transition to the first page, so that the user can login with his new credentials.

The process of user registration is managed by a button and Alamofire: once the button is clicked, the values the user inserted in the textfields are validated, then I start a post request, sending data to the server and receiving JSON data back in a while.

It's anything very simple (sorry for speaking too much), but in the end, after I receive the JSON, something strange happens here:

```
let j = JSON as! NSDictionary
let userStatus = j.object(forKey: "status")!

    if((userStatus as! Int) == 0){

        //
        print("user registerd")

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Registration ok", message: "Registration OK", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        let okAlert = UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .default, handler: {action in v.scrollToPreviousViewController() })

        alert.addAction(okAlert)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What is supposed to do this code? Once the user clicks the alert button, the pageviewcontroller should return with an animation to the login screen.

What happens? It returns back there but without animation.

This led me to think I should avoid "polluting" the global thread reserved to the GUI. And, in fact, I tried to put all the code inside a:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
```

without any success.

Then, I tried another thing:

```
let okAlert = UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .default, handler:
                                            {action in DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in v.scrollToPreviousViewController() }})
```

I don't perfectly understand why, but this practically works and eliminates the issue with the animation.

But that `unowned self` there generates a warning: "Capture self was never used". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't use `self` inside the async block then you will get this warning obviously. Please try with `_` instead of `self`.

Comment: It works. And it also works leaving only v.scrollToPreviousViewController(). But, is this the right way to do what I'm doing?  :-)

Comment: Yes that's perfect. Please accept the answer if you agree.

Comment: I accept the answer tomorrow if meanwhile someone doesn't post something interesting   :-)

Comment: If I replace with _ I get "Expected name of in closure capture list"

Answer (score 0):

to see what is swift capture list for, check this example ...

```
var i = 25

var cl = {print(i)}
var clc = {[i] in print(i)}

i = 35

cl()   // 35
clc()  // 25
```

the warning message "Capture self was never used" is therefore self-explanatory. you don't need to put self in your capture list, because you don't use it there

Comment: @IanBell which error, where? it works in my playground as expected

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, it was an XCode error, not your code   :-)